# How write the Mockito Junit Test Cases for JDBC Template in Spring Boot Application?

Tags: mockito, junit5

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    String sql = "select * from user_data";

    List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserRowMapper());

    return users;
}

public User getAUser(int userId) {
    String sql = "select * from user_data where userid=?";

    User user = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { userId }, new UserRowMapper());
    return user;
}

public User addUser(User user) {
    String SQL = "INSERT INTO user_data(user_first_name,user_last_name,mobile_no,about) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getMobileNumber(), user.getAbout());
    return user;
}
```

This is my Code. Can anyone please help me how to write Junit Mockito Test cases for that.

Comment: Hi @Subhasish, did you try to find tutorials about Mockito to understand this technology ? It's difficult on stackoverflow to explain entirely how this technology works. When you do this don't hesitate to return here and edit your question with some specific problems.

Comment: Thank you @JulienGavard for the reply. I have gone through the tutorials and understood about Mockito. But I am not able to get how to write test cases for JDBC Template. Can you please write the test cases for the 3 DAO methods. It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL request's testing, you cannot write unit tests. You have to write integration tests.

Two possible strategies :

- You can test with an in-memory database with tools like DbUnit (it's an old tool, I think you can find better nowadays)
- You can use an integration database. In a test, you execute your code, then you read the database to verify and finally you clean your database (you can use a transaction with rollback to clean automatically your operations).

Don't hesite to ask for advice when you advance in these ways.